# Enable Rest API on Spark Master

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-storage, cluster-computing, jira-rest-api

How can I enable REST API on Spark Master. I am having a Spark cluster with 3 nodes running on google cloud environment. REST API can be enabled in the spark-defaults.conf file with spark.master.rest.enabled to true. Is there any other method to do this?